# No rule to make target 'mailbox.c', needed by 'servod'

Tags: software-installation, make

[image: make: *** No rule to make target 'mailbox.c', needed by 'servod'. Stop.]

How can I solve this problem? 
I have got the file " servod.c" and "Makefile".
 I try to install "ServoBlaster".
After that this message showed up.

Comment: It means there's a source file that isn't where the makefile says it is.  You should provide more context about how you got to where you are.

Comment: "wget raw.githubusercontent.com/richardghirst/PiBits/master/…; And "wget raw.githubusercontent.com/richardghirst/PiBits/master/…; This is what I typed into the terminal before I typed"make servod".

Comment: You need to edit your question and detail the exact commands you gave and the system's response.  Preferably by cutting & pasting the text.

Comment: Your question makes a great counter-example for the kind of content we strive to have here. Meaningless title (with an exclamation mark), screenshot of the error message (copy/pasting text is too hard?), spelling mistakes, unclear context. Please try to do better next time.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `wget` to fetch files from github. Use `git`:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits
cd PiBits/ServoBlaster/user
make servod
```

The file `mailbox.c` is [right there](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/blob/master/ServoBlaster/user/mailbox.c) in the repository. `wget` has no means to know you need it, but `git` does.